# Почему парсится различное количество элементов?

Tags: python, многопоточность

Есть парсер, который с нескольких страничек извлекает все ссылки. Парсер написан с использованием модуля threadings. проблема в том, что после каждого запуска результат содержит различное количество ссылок.

Хотя я ставлю замок перед операцией добавления очередной части ссылок в глобальную переменную. После операции добавления я замок снимаю. Я думал, это поможет избежать неожиданностей, но не помогло.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import threading


lock = threading.RLock()
all_items = []
links = [
    'http://google.com',
    'http://yandex.ru',
    'http://microsoft.com',
    'http://ebay.com',
    'http://ozon.ru',
]


def get_items(html_text):
    paths = []
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text, 'lxml')
    link_obj = soup.find('html').find_all('a')

    for path in link_obj:
        paths.append(path['href'])

    return paths


def recieve_page_html(link):
    with requests.Session() as session:
        html = session.get(link)
        items = get_items(html.text)
        lock.acquire()
        try:
            all_items.extend(items)
        finally:
            lock.release()


workers = []
for link in links:
    th = threading.Thread(target=recieve_page_html, args=(link,))
    th.start()
    workers.append(th)

for w in workers:
    w.join()

print('\n LENGTH: ', len(all_items))
```

Comment: А что отдает программа, если убрать многопоточность. Количество ссылок одно и то же или нет ?

Comment: @n1tr0xs да, 386 ссылок всегда

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Количество ссылок меняется не из-за ошибки в коде, а из-за сайтов [Ebay](http://ebay.com) и [Ozon](http://ozon.ru).